# ansible-playbook -> ControlPath too long

Tags: macos, ssh, yaml, ansible

I just trying ouy a playbook that a  colleague has set up that I needed to modify. The first problem I get running on my mac was

```
ERROR: Unable to find an inventory file, specify one with -i ?
```

This was easily solved by adding *-i verif* to the command. But then the following error occured.

```
loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/andreas.joelsson/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
ControlPath too long
```

This is true for all 8 machines (*loadgen-verif-app[1-8].internal.machines*)

After some debugging that the file could be too long, I tried the following command with the same result:

```
ansible nukes -m ping -i verif -vvvv
```

then I thought it was issues with ssh but executing the command through ssh works:

```
ssh loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines ping loadgen-verif-app2.internal.machines
```

And now I am stumped because the ping command works on some of the machines not in the range listed above, the thing is that they are shorter than the *loagenXXX.machines* path if that makes it an issue. But then the ssh command shouldn't work I guess.

I have some ssh config settings set up for the targets as well, but that is no different that the ones that did work with the ping command.

```
Host loadgen1
    HostName loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines
```

Now I am stumped as it works for the colleague on a mac as well. So not sure if there is some setting i'm missing or similar. He doesn't need to provide the *-i verif* either that can also be a reason why it doesn't work.

**edit 2014-12-17:**

- Have tried modifying the ansible setting control_path according to http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#control-path
- We are running the same version of ansible
- We are running the same version of OpenSSH.
- We have the same ssh configs as far as we can tell.
- Have been looking for Host* that I found in /etc/ssh_config and removed without progress according to f.e. https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202186044-Unable-to-git-clone-an-application-when-SSH-session-sharing-is-in-use-ControlPath-too-long-

**edit 2015-01-08:**

```
SE-C02N76PGG5RP:verif_provisioning andreas.joelsson$ ansible loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines -m ping -i verif -vvvv
<loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: andreas.joelsson
<loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/andreas.joelsson/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1420723708.99-33622628424665 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1420723708.99-33622628424665 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1420723708.99-33622628424665'
loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/andreas.joelsson/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
ControlPath too long
```

**edit 2015-02-12:**

```
SE-C02N76PGG5RP:verif_provisioning andreas.joelsson$ ansible nukes -m ping -i verif
loadgen-verif-app4.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app5.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app3.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app2.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app8.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app6.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
loadgen-verif-app7.internal.machines | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
```

And with the working one:

```
SE-C02N76PGG5RP:verif_provisioning andreas.joelsson$ ansible duke -m ping -i verif
steve-verif-app1.internal.machines | success >> {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Comment: Did your colleague send you his ansible.cfg file, and do you have all the same (and related) config files in the right locations on your mac as a result? That appears to be the first thing to check...

Comment: Same config as it was in the git repo i checked out, is there some other place like home folder where settings can be stored?

Comment: apart from the commandline options, the config is stated in the ansible.cfg file - you might want to check that you are using the same version of ansible (ansible -v I think).

Comment: Yep, using the same version now, or I used a newer one that he upgraded to with the same result, we think it is ssh issue with control path but making the change that is suggested by ansible did nothing (http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#control-path).

Answer (score 6):

Solution to this error is mentioned at ansible documentation, please refer to this [link](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#control-path).

I was getting this error, when I tried to connect to EC2 instances but after modifying the below mentioned configuration, it solved my problem.

I am supposing that you have installed the ansible on Mac using pip. So, please do these steps:

1. create the `/etc/ansible` directory

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/ansible
   ```
2. change the permission of it

   ```
   sudo chown $(whoami):staff /etc/ansible
   ```
3. download the `ansible.cfg` file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) and place inside the `/etc/ansible` directory
4. edit/uncomment the following line

   ```
   [ssh_connection]
   control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
   ```
5. edit the `~/.ssh/config` file:

   ```
   Host *
     GSSAPIAuthentication no
   ```

EXTRA STEP:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/eugeneoden/homebrew/eca9de1/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

Comment: I used brew to install. And in the root of the git repo where I have ansible I added the control_path under default, like:           [defaults]
roles_path = roles
control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r

Comment: did that work for you or are you facing any problem?

Comment: I haven't tried your solution, and the path locally doesn't work. Is it the same for brew so I should add the steps that you suggest?

Comment: Tries your suggestion but did not work either. Seems the host names are too long event with the config modified. I can access a hostname with the name: steve-verif-app1.internal.machines, but not one with the name loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines. I have tried to shorten the name in .ssh/config and /etc/hosts without any luck.

Comment: can you please run with -vvvv and share the result please. Thanks

Comment: Added output above for better formatting. See the last edit from today.

Comment: please do the step 5 and extra step, and one more important thing, do you have andreas.joelsson user on the remote machine, if not then run the command like this:    ansible loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines -m ping -i verif -vvvv -u USERNAME_that_exist_on_remote_machines                              By the way, loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines is your group name? you can make it small, if it is. Thanks

Comment: Tried the steps without any luck, still controlpath too long. It is not a group name but the name of the host. Using the group loadgens will make the same issue, only for all hosts but one. (loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines fails while steve-verif-app1.internal.machines works). I exist as that user on the remote machine as well.

Comment: what's the result of this command from your terminal (ssh andreas.joelsson@loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines), it got success?

Comment: yep:  SE-C02N76PGG5RP:verif_provisioning andreas.joelsson$ ssh andreas.joelsson@loadgen-verif-app1.internal.machines
Last login: Fri Jan  9 09:04:37 2015 from 10.4.136.154
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
[andreas.joelsson@loadgen-verif-app1 ~]$
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_

Comment: really strange, can you please do this inside the ansible.cfg file: host_key_checking = False, and also clear the ~/.ansible directry and test again, as you mentioned that you have 1 to 8 hosts, try to ping another host, or even try to ping any other server beside these 8 servers please. If I am not wrong, you are using these server inside the vagrant?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, has been alot going on in my life, I will show output in the above post from the first host, and then with the second that worked. Same as before though with the issues. Feels like there is an issue with the length.

Answer (score 2):

Ok the way I got it working was that I did the changes in `ansible.cfg` and the extra steps but it did not work. The only way I found is to export `ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH`:

This is coz, I think it always is picking the default path. Even after the change in `ansible.cfg`

```
  1.9.4 git:(master) pwd                                                                                                                                            
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.9.4
➜  1.9.4 git:(master) ag ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL
libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/constants.py
187:ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH       = get_config(p, 'ssh_connection', 'control_path', 'ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH', "%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r")
```

Output without exporting `ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTOL_PATH`:

```
ControlPath="/Users/vinitkhandagle/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r"
```

Exported the variable as:

```
export ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH='%(directory)s/%%h-%%r'
```

Control path changes accordingly:

```
ControlPath="/Users/vinitkhandagle/.ansible/cp/%h-%r"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note to @techraf above comment is that I encountered the same issue when using **ansible** in combination with **molecule** in a **virtual environment**. So even though `ansible.cfg` has been read. `ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH` will be overwritten. So in that case a workaround was to set it as environment variable outside the configuration file itself. As this is then shorter than the default path.

`export ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH='%(directory)s/tmp'`